# Loop through a field in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch the names of tables in a database and create a table in another database with the data.

The table names vary week by week so Im trying to do some automation.

Iv created a temp table with the names of the tables. Im not sure how to loop through the tables and run a SQL statement for each table name.

I dont have any code except creation of the temp table.

Temp table is created. What next?

Comment: If I try to understand your question, you already have table names in your temporary table? Now you wanna do is, Generate create table statements and then generate insert statements (using the values in the existing table) so you can execute these satements in another database?

Comment: Yes that is what Im trying to accomplish

Comment: I have the table names...now I need to loop through the temp table and get the table names so I can create new tables in another database

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach (without a temporary table) is to generate and execute a dynamic statement:

```
USE [CurrentDatabase]
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''

SELECT @stm = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT CONCAT(
            N'; SELECT * ',
            'INTO [NewDatabase].',
            QUOTENAME(sch.[name]),
            N'.',
            QUOTENAME(tab.[name]),
            N' FROM ',
            QUOTENAME(sch.[name]),
            N'.',
            QUOTENAME(tab.[name]),
            N'WHERE 1 = 0 '
        )
        FROM sys.tables tab 
        JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
        WHERE tab.[type] = 'U'
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, N''
)

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Comment: Zhorov,  It looks like your code repeats the insert action 4 times. Is that what its doing?

Comment: @BuckPowell It generates a statement with INSERT's for each table. Just see the output from `PRINT @stm`. Thanks.

Comment: This is a great way to handle this kind of thing without resorting to a cursor. Well done!!

Comment: @BuckPowell No, `SELECT * FROM sys.tables tab JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id WHERE tab.[type] = 'U'` returns information about all user tables in a database. The other part of the code generates a dynamic statement using`FOR XML PATH('')`.

Comment: @BuckPowell Using `QUOTENAME` four times is for generating `SELECT * INTO [schema].[table] FROM [schema].[table]` statements, not for naming four tables. Probably that is more correct answer to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table names and insert them in your temp table using:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE YOUR_TEMP_TABLE

INSERT INTO YOUR_TEMP_TABLE THE_COLUMN_NAME 
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

I included the truncate table because as you say the table names change often and it's a temp table, so truncate gives you a "clean slate" to start with every time.

Comment: This will give all the tables, including system tables, shall he not add Where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' ? @Nick

Comment: Of course if this is an actual temp table truncating it would be kind of pointless. But the issue here is this answer is only the first part of the solution. It gets the list of tables, which the OP says the already have. But it doesn't create the copy of the tables which is what the OP is really asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after.

```
    --assuming both dbs are with-in the same server

    --select top 10 name into TempTableList from SourceDBName..sysobjects  where xtype='u' and uid=1

    declare @sourceDB varchar(100),
            @Table varchar(100)

    set @sourceDB='SourceDBName.SchemaName.'        
    -- if you are working with different schema have them listed in your temp table

    declare generateTable cursor 
    for
    select * from TempTableList -- The temp table that you already have data with
    Open generateTable

    fetch next from generateTable into @Table
    while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    begin
    /*Same drill if you need them to be on specific schemas, you can alter this part.*/
    exec('select top 0 * into '+@Table+'_new from ' +@sourceDB+ @Table)

    fetch next from generateTable into @Table

    end
    close generateTable
    deallocate generateTable
```

If you want to fill them with the same data then just do

```
    exec('select * into '+@Table+'_new from ' + @Table)
```

Comment: Praveen,

Does your script create separate tables based on table name?

Comment: Yeah, assuming the table names are in TempTableList.

Comment: I get an error stating Cursor is not open at line "fetch next from generateTable into @Table"
Also why declare @sourceDB when its not used in this script?

Comment: I added the line "OPEN generateTable" before the line "fetch next from generateTable into @Table"

No tables are created.

Comment: I had changed the script now to use that variable. But are you running the whole script? Can you share your version of the query? Is the open cursor in the comments?

Comment: Update...I got it to work. I had to add the USE database first then prefix the table names with dbo.

Thanks a load! I appreciate it

Comment: Ok great work...but now I have an additional requirement. 
The tables that were generated are prefixed with "Aggregate". The Aggregate tables are the summary of the actual tables. I need the tables to be generated based on the actual data (e.g. Aggregate_2959 = Response_2959. So the tables I need should be the Response tables.

Comment: Additional Update...
I populated the temp table with the response tables like below:

SELECT 'Response' + right(TABLE_NAME, 5)  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'TachyonResponses' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Ag%'